# OTP autofill for mobile browser Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, sms

I managed to configure API WebOTP, though it is not supported in Firefox.

For some reason, I'm struggling to find another OTP autofill API which is suitable for Firefox.

Any suggestions?

Comment: webotp isn't supported, and since `This feature is experimental. Use caution before using in production.` why do you care if it works or not?